Cloth simulation is getting stuck inside collision mesh whenever it touches it the collision object
Whenever my cloth simulation object touches this collision, the cloth sort of goes inside of the collision. I've been at it for about 1 hour now, and I couldn't find a fix online. I've tried remeshing my collision object, adding quality to the cloth simulation and I recalculated the normals. The cloth simulation is not the problem as it works normally with a sphere.




This happened to me because of "self collision". I found that that option was unnecessary. If you share your file it's easier to find the answer.

I turned off "Self Collisions", sadly no difference. Here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HnsIBIQHBcYz_Z3iQaTAWDewtljeMm2R/view?usp=sharing. Thank you!

You have not applied the Scale (Ctrl+A) to the hand object and the X value is negative (-10). I guess you want to mirror the hand. However, this also flips the normals so that the model is turned inside out and the collision detection system sucks in the cloth. The fix is simple: first, apply the Scale, then do to Edit mode and recalculated the normals.

Thank you so much man!

You have not applied the Scale (Ctrl+A) to the hand object and the X value is negative (-10). (I guess you want to mirror the hand.) However, the negative scale flips the normals so that the model is turned inside out and the collision detection system sucks in the cloth. You will see the flipped normals when you have applied the Scale.
I also would apply the Rotation to the hand object, and the Scale to the sock object because the scale is also non-uniform (0.600, 0.300, 0.600) and this can cause further issues.

The fix is simple: first, apply the Scale to the hand object, then go to Edit mode and Recalculate the Normals to fix the normals (Shift+N or menu Mesh > Normals > ...).

